# Are there tools to document Web UI standards across all applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-experience, web-standards, code-documentation

We want a way for all our .NET developers to follow a consistent standard when building web UI in terms of javascript, html and CSS. For example all confirmation, warning and errors messages should have the same look and feel. Plus have a way to reference the code snippet in central location/portal instead of digging code from a set of different applications.

Maybe similar to Bootstrap on how we can reference code snippets with live examples and have it organize thru a table of context:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
http://getbootstrap.com/css/
http://getbootstrap.com/components/
```

A nice to have if we can have integrate with VS Team Services (formerly VSO)

**Note: We use Bootstrap and other javascript plugin and libraries for our Web UI**

Comment: You can use resource labels and have no string literals in your code. This will allow two good practices. The same resource  can be reused and will always be consistent with one place to check for spelling and or grammar errors. Also, the files can be sent away and translated to multiple languages and your app is automatically localized when you add the new language specific resource files.